# For test_datagen.flow from directory, what should I specify the class_mode?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imagedatagenerator

I'm attempting to create a CNN model using image data. My entire data set was divided into train, test, and validation. I used `class_mode = 'categorical'` for the training data since training data needs labels, and `class_mode = None` for the test data because testing shouldn't be done with labels.
the snippet of code

```
train_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1 / 255.0,
        rotation_range=20,
        zoom_range=0.05,
        width_shift_range=0.05,
        height_shift_range=0.05,
        shear_range=0.05,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest"
    )

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1/255,
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_dir,
    target_size=(height, width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)

valid_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=val_dir,
    target_size=(height, width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)


test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/content/drive/MyDrive/MonkeyPox/output/test",
    target_size=(height, width),
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode=None,   **here**
    shuffle=False,
    seed=42
)
```

when I specify `class_moede=None` in the `test_generator`,

```
model.evaluate(test_generator, batch_size=16)
```

the loss & accuracy is [0.0, 0.0], which means my model is failed to evaluate

again  when I specify `class_moede='categorical' in the` test_generator`` ,

```
model.evaluate(test_generator, batch_size=16)
```

it gives a certain loss and accuracy

My question is why i am getting [0.0, 0.0] when i am using `class_moede=None` in the `test_generator` ?

Comment: Why do you think testing shouldn't be done with labels? This is incorrect.

Comment: But we only use photos for testing, right? If we gave our model the labels for the photos, would it not correctly predict every image?

Comment: No, the labels are not given to the model. Testing does not work as training. To test a model and compute some metric, you need labels, to compare the prediction with the correct label, this is why accuracy and loss are zero if there are no labels.

Comment: You need to specify the class_mode='categorical' while fetching the test dataset if you have multiple category input data in the test dataset which will yield the output(Label) accordingly. This is why the accuracy and loss result is 0 if you specify the class_mode=None but have multiple categories input in the test dataset.